# session goes null when I host my website in IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-config, session-variables

When a user LogsIn I am creating a Session, Session["Username"] and I am using it in my masterpage. This is working fine when I am working on visual studio but when I host this on IIS 6.0, my session goes null.
I tried alot and included this in web.config but no luck

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout ="60" cookieless="false"></sessionState>
```

This question may be duplicate but I have checked the previous answers but my problem didn't got solved. I am using Oracle 11g database and Asp.net 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem:

```
mode="InProc"
```

This means that the session data will be kept in memory in the process. But IIS can decide to recycle the Application Pool at any time wiping all session data. For this reason you might consider storing this session state in a dedicated store. One possibility is to use the SQL server store:

```
model="sqlserver"
```

Checkout the different [`sessions state stores`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) available.

`InProc` session state mode should only be used for development purposes and never in production.

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g database not sqlserver. will it work for me because I am getting error  `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

Comment: You need to specify the connection string to the SQL database where the sessions will be stored. Please read the article I have linked to in my answer which explains in more details how to use SqlServer session state mode. I doubt that this will work with Oracle database though. You might consider using a state server mode as well if SQL is not an option for you. But again if the state server is restarted, sessions will be lost - it is not as persistent as SQL but much better compared to in memory.